# iPad: Popover windows got resized iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1050, 900);

[wineAdminPopup presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:master.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Hi I put the above code to make a popup in a tableview. However it doesn't popup in the whole screen. If I want to center it in the iPad screen with no arrow or arrow in the center. How can i do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rect` parameter in `presentPopoverFromRect:...` specifies the rectangle at which to anchor the popover, not the size of the presented popover. That would be specified by setting `contentSizeForViewInPopover` on the popover's content view controller.

If you don't want the arrows and don't need the specific behavior of popovers, then you could 
present your view controller modally:

```
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen; // or UIModalPresentationFormSheet
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

`presentModalViewController` is deprecated in iOS 6 and above. Use `presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil` (parameters `animated` and `completion` can be set depending on your requirements). Also if you want to resize yourViewController you need to change `self.view.frame` and next time your view controller will be of that size.